About the use of Bayes' rule for continuous valued random variables
I am currently studying the book "An introduction to statistical learning with application in Python" and I am currently at the part 4 of chapter 4 where they explain the general framework for Linear discriminant analysis: "In this new approach, we model
the distribution of the predictors $X$ separately in each of the response
classes (i.e. for each value of $Y$ ). We then use Bayes’ theorem to flip these
around into estimates for $\Pr(Y = k\mid X = x)$". In the book, we note $f_k(X) ≡ \Pr(X\mid Y = k)$ as the density function of X and $\pi_k$ represent the overall
or prior probability that a randomly chosen observation comes from the prior
$k$th class ($Y$ takes finite value). The formula is $$\Pr(Y = k\mid X = x) = \frac{\pi_kf_k(x)}
{\sum_{\ell=1}^K \pi_\ell f_\ell(x)}$$
I understand perfectly if $X$ takes discrete values but I am a bit confused if $X$ takes continued values. What would be the equivalent statement of Bayes' rule if $Y$ is discrete and $X$ is continuous and could you provide a reference for the proof ?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Your notation is in some ways rather strange and unclear.  Where you wrote $\Pr(X\mid Y=k),$ might you have meant $\Pr(X=x\mid Y=k)\text{?}$ If so, then to the left of the "=", you need $f(x),$ not $f(X).$

Bayes rule is stated for events, and the event you condition on is usually taken to have non-zero probability. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem
$$
P\left[A\,\big|\,B\right]=\frac{P[A \,\cap\,B]}{P\left[B\right]},\quad P\left[B\right]>0
$$
In the continuous case you would have to have something like:
$$
P\left[y\in\left(a_0,a_1\right)\,\big|\,x\in\left(b_0,b_1\right)\right]=\frac{P[y\in\left(a_0,a_1\right) \,\cap\,x\in\left(b_0,b_1\right)]}{P\left[x\in\left(b_0,b_1\right)\right]},\quad P\left[x\in\left(b_0,b_1\right)\right]>0
$$
You could then take $a_1=\delta+a_0$ and $b_1=\nu\cdot\delta + b_0$, where $\delta>0$ but small and $\nu>0$ and finite. Using:
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\delta->0}P\left[y\in\left(a_0,a_1\right) \,\cap\,x\in\left(b_0,b_1\right)\right]&=f_{XY}\left(b,a\right)\nu\delta^2+\mathcal{O}\left(\delta^3\right)\\
a&=\frac{a_0+a_1}{2}\\
b&=\frac{b_0+b_1}{2}\\
\lim_{\delta->0}P[x\in\left(b_0,b_1\right)]&=f_X\left(b\right)\nu\delta+\mathcal{O}\left(\delta^2\right)\\
f_X\left(b\right)&=\int dy \,f_{XY}\left(x,y,\right)
\end{align}
$$
For appropriate probability densities. You can now define the conditional probability density for Y:
$$
\lim_{\delta->0}P\left[y\in\left(a_0,a_1\right) \,\Big|\,x\in\left(b_0,b_1\right)\right]=f_{Y\,|\,X=b}\left(a\right)\delta+\mathcal{O}\left(\delta^2\right)
$$
With this you will find that:
$$
f_{Y\,|\,X=b}\left(a\right)=\frac{f_{XY}\left(b,a\right)}{f_X\left(b\right)}
$$
I guess, my point here would be that there is not much to prove. The definition of conditional density is such that Bayes rule works, similar to discrete case. One can do some work to show that conditional density defined in this way is a probability density.

"Bayes rule is stated for events" Not necessarily. Bayes's original paper on this dealt with prior and posterior distributions of a continuous random variable.

This is best understood as the measure-theoretic conditional probability, as thoroughly discussed in this post. More specifically, we need to show that $\frac{\pi_kf_k(X)}{f(X)}$ (with $f(X) = \sum_l \pi_l f_l(X)$) as defined in the OP is a version of the measure-theoretic conditional probability $P(Y = k \mid X)$. As for the subtle difference between $P(Y = k \mid X)$ and $P(Y = k \mid X = x)$, refer to this answer.
In order to verify this, it suffices to show that for any $G \in \sigma(X)$, the following identity holds (for simplicity, denote the event $\{Y = k\}$ by $A_k$):
\begin{align*}
\int_G \frac{\pi_kf_k(X)}{f(X)}dP = P(A_k \cap G). \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
Before heading to prove $\eqref{1}$, we must clarify the definition of $f_k(x)$. In the original question, it is defined as "$P(X | Y = k)$", which is probably a typo. It should be recognized as the "conditional density" (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) for the $k$-th subpopulation such that for any Borel set $H$:
\begin{align*}
P(X \in H | A_k) = \int_H f_k(x) dx. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
Note that $\eqref{2}$ implies that the marginal density of $X$ is given by $f(x) = \sum_l \pi_l f_l(x)$, because by the law of total probability:
\begin{align*}
P(X \in H) &= \sum_l P(X \in H | A_l)P(A_l) = \sum_l \pi_l\int_Hf_l(x)dx \\
&= \int_H \sum_l\pi_lf_l(x) dx = \int_H f(x)dx. 
\end{align*}
Therefore, by the change-of-variable formula, for $G = X^{-1}(H)$, the left hand side of $\eqref{1}$ is
\begin{align*}
 & \int_H\frac{\pi_k f_k(x)}{f(x)}f(x)dx = \int_H\pi_k f_k(x)dx \\
=& P(A_k)P(X \in H | A_k) = P(\{X \in H\} \cap A_k) = P(A_k \cap G). 
\end{align*}
This shows that $\eqref{1}$ holds for pre-image sets $G$.  Since those sets generate $\sigma(X)$, $\eqref{1}$ also holds for all $\sigma(X)$-sets $G$.
This completes the proof.

I'm taking $\pi_k$ to mean $\Pr(Y=k).$ I'm going to write $f_{X\,\mid\,Y\,=\,k} (x)$ to mean the value at (lower-case) $x$ of the conditional density function of the random variable (capital) $X,$ given the event that $Y=k.$ That is sensible notation. Sensible notation is rare. All density functions are densities with respect to an underlying measure, and in this case that measure assigns to every interval on the real line the length of that interval. I will denote that measure by $dx.$ Then the conditional probability distribution of $X,$ given the event $Y=k,$ is $f_{X\,\mid\,Y\,=\,k}(x) \, dx$ $(\text{with } “dx”).$
The prior probability distribution of $Y$ is $f_Y(k) = \Pr(Y=k).$
The likelihood function is $L(k) = \Pr(X=x\mid Y=k),$ i.e. a function of $k,$ not of $x.$ This is not any sort of probability measure or probability density – note in particular that the sum $\sum_k L(k)$ need not be $1.$
The posterior probability distribution of $Y,$ i.e. its conditional probability distribution given the event $Y=k,$ is
$$
k \mapsto \Pr(Y=k \mid X=x) = c f_Y(k) L(k)
$$
where $c$ is whatever number will make the sum of these values over all values of $k$ equal to $1.$ That is
$$
c= \frac1 {\sum_k f_Y(k) L(k)}.
$$
Bayes's theorem can be stated as follows: Multiplying the prior distribution by the likelihood function and then normalizing yields the posterior distribution.
